# How to store 2D array in the matrix format (with commas)

Tags: java, mysql

Lets keep this simple. I have been trying for many hours and unable to find a solution.

I am retrieving the following data from a MySQL database. The DB is in the current format.

```
|number1|number2|number3|number4|number5|
|   0   |   1   |   0   |   1   |   0   |
|   1   |   0   |   1   |   0   |   1   |
|   0   |   1   |   0   |   1   |   0   |
|   1   |   0   |   1   |   0   |   1   |
|   0   |   1   |   0   |   1   |   0   |
```

I have the following code to retrieve it (which works fine):

```
int[][] array = new int[5][5];

            int i = 0;
                while(result.next()) {
                    array[i][0] = result.getInt(1);                   
                    array[i][1] = result.getInt(2);                   
                    array[i][2] = result.getInt(3);                   
                    array[i][3] = result.getInt(4);                   
                    array[i][4] = result.getInt(5);                   

                    for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
                        System.out.print(array[i][j]);
                    }

                    i++;
                }
```

However, when returning the array, i want it to be in the following format (e.g with the comma's and curly brackets in the right place so that i can parse this 2d array (directly using the variable "array" and use it directly when doing requests with other objects).

```
int[][] array = {
                { 0, 1, 0, 1, 0 },
                { 1, 0, 1, 0, 1 },
                { 0, 1, 0, 1, 0 },
                { 1, 0, 1, 0, 1 },
                { 0, 1, 0, 1, 0 },

};
```

EDIT: TO be more clear:
Say i have another variable called secondaryArray[][]. I want to assign my array retrieved from the database to secondaryArray, but in the current format, it wont let me because the contents are not in the matrix format.

Thank you for your time and help! Mostly appreciated

Comment: Doesn't it return similar to that automatically, just not formatted like it? Is that the question you are asking?

Comment: @RileyCarney Thanks for the reply Riley. Currently, it is done via system.out.print function. I want it to make sure that the array variable can be formatted like the last example i showed, with commas and curly brackets. Sorry if it sounds confusing.

Comment: Ok, to be more clear, i have another variable called secondaryArray[][] with  the same contents. I want to assign my array retrieved from the database to secondaryArray, but in the current format, it wont let me.

Comment: Just loop and assign (but if **same contents**) why would you do this..

Comment: @PetterFriberg Just think of it as i want to essentially put the new contents from the array to the secondaryArray. Updating each time whenever i call a specific method(). The problem is currently, as the output format is different, i cannot perform the assignment.

Comment: You are on the wrong track, check how to loop your array and how to assign... there are many examples on SO looping array's, if you don't find tell me and I will help you out

Comment: How is array assignment related to how the code is formatted? The brace and commas are visualization tools when you think in terms of Java object and are not part of the object representation. Please rephrase your question a bit.

Comment: @Milky it seems you are correct. I have got mixed up between the underlying structure and the visualization. Thank you for all the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can '*put the new contents from the array to the secondaryArray*'

**Code for copying a multidimensional array:**

```
int[][] secondaryArray = new int[array.length][]; // Creates the amount row in array
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) 
{ 
    secondaryArray[i] = new int[array[i].length]; // Creates the columns in array
    for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) 
        secondaryArray[i][j] = array[i][j];
}
```

I believe it works for both ragged and nonragged arrays

Here is how they would print out (just reading the integers)

```
0101010101010101010101010
```

Comment: Thank you. This was very useful